# Perl6 optional function flags

Tags: raku

How can I implement functions that take an optional flag in Perl6? For example, say that I want to invoke my function like this:

```
format 'a b c';
```

or like this:

```
format :pretty 'a b c';
```

How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's just a named argument, in case of flags a boolean one. This all works out because `:pretty` is syntactic sugar for the pair `:pretty(True)` aka `pretty => True`.

You can either use the boolean value

```
sub format($arg, Bool :$pretty = False) {
    if $pretty { ... }
    else { ... }
}
```

or use its presence for multi-dispatch

```
multi format($arg) { ... }
multi format($arg, Bool :$pretty!) { ... }
```

In the first example, we provided a default value (which isn't really necessary as the undefined value boolifies to `False`, but it's arguably the 'right thing to do' semantically), in the second one we made it a required parameter by adding the `!`.

Also note that named arguments still have to be separated by commas, ie you'd use it as

```
format :pretty, 'a b c';
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really want that odd syntax, you can use an operator and some subsignature magic. The `Bool` method is optional and the class `Pretty` can be empty. It's just there to provide something for the MMD-dispatcher to hold onto.

```
class Pretty { method Bool {True} };
sub prefix:<:pretty>(|c){ Pretty.new, c };
multi sub format((Pretty:D $pretty, |a)){ dd $pretty.Bool, a };
multi sub format(|c){ dd c };
format :pretty 'a b c'; format 'a b c';
# OUTPUT«Bool::True␤\(\("a b c"))␤\("a b c")␤»
```